# Can we add Custom Profile center URL in %%ProfilecenterURL%%?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In an email, I want to redirect to a custom profile center page, is there a way to change the value of the `%%profile_center_url%%` so that it goes to a custom page instead of the default?

Answer (score 4):

SFMC Support can change the value for the `%%profile_center_url%%` to whatever you want -- as [@Kenneth](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/36789/kenneth-wagner) mentioned.

I typically do this, which I outline [**here**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/a-case-for-the-micrositeurl-function/):

`<a href='%%=MicrositeURL(888888,"subscriberMID", "12345678")=%%'>Update Profile</a>`

Then in the profile center page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

    </script>
    %%[set @subscriberMID = RequestParameter("subscriberMID")]%%
    <script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    if (Variable.GetValue("@subscriberMID") != "") {
        memberid = Variable.GetValue("@subscriberMID");
    } else {
        memberid = Attribute.GetValue("memberid");
    }

</script>
```

Same thing can be done with the [**CloudPagesURL()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/) function.

**Update**

Since the CloudPagesURL() doesn't do URL parameters properly, here's my preferred way of doing this with the [**CloudPagesURL()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/) function:

```
<a href='%%=redirectto(concat(CloudPagesURL(1234),"&mid=", memberid))=%%'>Preference Center</a>
```

Then in SSJS:

```
SetVar("mid", Request.GetQueryStringParameter("mid"));

function SetVar(varName, varValue){
    request[varName] = varValue ? varValue : "";
    Variable.SetValue(varName, varValue);
}
```

Comment: Why you choose SSJS over AmpScript for your preference centers?

Comment: You can use arrays in SSJS.

Comment: Ever since I read the post by @AdamSpriggs, I have used the MicrositeURL function. It's awesome.

Comment: Thanks ! In the global MC Footer I the redirectTo doesn't seem to work (the URL that appears in the email is https://user-content.s50.sfmc-content.com/%%=RedirectTo ..)

Is it necessary to not use the Company footer but instead to define one in a template ?

Answer (score 3):

I would advise the following:

1. Building the preference center in [Cloud pages](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/cloudpages/) and use the [CloudPagesURL](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/#cloudpagesURL) function to form the redirect link. This has the added advantage of encrypting subscriber information. 
   No
2. Normally not using the default profile center link would throw an error. This can by bypassed by either still including it and hiding the link, or contacting your account executive .
3. You can also use the Ampscript below to hack it:

   `%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%%%profile_center_url%%%%[endif]%%`

Answer (score -1):

We can't change system generated %%profilecenterurl%% to update profile that gives preview error,but if we want to navigate to custom page profile center LP/Cloud page URL u need to mask the system generated profile center.

Below way we can do it

step 1 : Hide System Generated Profile center using css property

`[a style="display:none;" href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile"]`

Step 2 : Add one more href and redirect to your custom profile center landing page.

`[a href="https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/s3o0c2hx33i" alias="Update Profile"]`

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Have you reached out to support? They can disable these validations for you, so you do not need to hide anything. Also, i believe that they might also be able to change the URL to the profile center at a system level?

Comment: Using the raw URL for a custom preference center is leaving out all of the benefits of the subscriber context you get with the [cloudpagesurl()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/) and [micrositeurl()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/micrositeurl/) functions.