# Display (or host) the Default Profile Center on a custom url?

Tags: marketing-cloud, profile-center

There are a few posts and answers as for how to implement a Custom Profile Center.

Evalutations talk about a 30-50 hours effort, which the client doesn't have budget for.

So, my question is a bit different:

What'd be the simplest way to keep the Default profile center page, but host it on a custom url.

- We have SAP enabled.

So, for example, the Default profile center would show on:
https://my-preference.my-SAP-domain.com
or
https://my-SAP-domain.com/preference-center

**PS**

I have seen the following hack to bypassing profile center validation in emails, so only need to know how to host the profile center elsewhere (ideally).

```
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%%%profile_center_url%%%%[endif]%%
```

Source: 
[Can we add Custom Profile center URL in %%ProfilecenterURL%%?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179177/can-we-add-custom-profile-center-url-in-profilecenterurl)

Alternatively, a 301 redirection could be used, but it's less clean and missing the point.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the goal? If it is to have the profile page shown embedded on your customers website, you could maybe think about an iframe. I was never a fan of it, but many people use it. You would need to pass along the query string from the initial profile center page link. Never did it, but should be possible.

Comment: That's exactly the goal, yes.

Am not fan of iframe either, end "pass to an iframe", would have to see if this is even possible, I'd expect the GET variable to be encrypted in some way. Would have to look at how the Profile Center link is built.  Assuming this is possible, and I can simply pass a variable -  would you use PHP or client-side JS to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request to Salesforce support and check if they can able change the default Profile Center URL to your SAP Based URL.

If they couldn't able to do then you can try to with this as a work around:

1. Create a data extension. lets say 'ProfileCenter_DE' with 2 attributes - Id and ProfileCenter_URL.
2. Add the below AMPscript on all the email you can add it in email
   templates it would be better

   > ```
   > %%[
   > Set @URL = AttributeValue("profile_center_url")
   > Set @jobID = [jobid]
   > Set @batchId = [_JobSubscriberBatchID]
   > Set @subscriberkey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
   > Set @Id = concat(@subscriberkey,@batchId,@jobID)
   > InsertDE('ProfileCenter_DE','Id',@Id,'ProfileCenter_URL',@URL)
   > ]%%
   > ```
3. In the URL pointing it to profile center add the link as `href="CloudPageURL?%%=v(@Id)=%%"`
4. In the Cloud page you can add the below to populate the default
   profile center in Iframe

.

```
%%[
Set @Id = RequestParameter("Id")
Set @URL = Lookup("ProfileCenter_DE","ProfileCenter_URL","Id",@Id) 
]%%
URL - %%=v(@URL)=%%
<iframe src="%%=v(@URL)=%%" style="width:100%; height:100%;">

</iframe>
```

You can also use 301 redirection but note that profile center will generate URL dynamically you would have to redirect the dynamic URL.

Comment: Amazing @Naveen ! I have opened a case with SFMC as it would be the cleanest way, but your workaround is very elegant. Definitely worth a shot! PS. What's the difference between jobID and Batch ID? and I'm curious -  why do we want to capture these as well? Subscriberkey is unique - so my instinct would have been to use only SubscriberKey as the ID (no Concat). Why concatenate the other two?

Comment: @LimeWeb,every email send is associated with JobID. its like 1:1 between email send and job ID. Batch ID - Identifies the batch associated with a triggered email send event also normal send. This value defaults to 0 for a marketing list send. You are correct, if you are using UpsertDE then you can use only with subscriber key. If you are using InsertDE you have to use a combination of Subscriberkey,JobID and BatchID to get a unique value. Also, I have tried it in my instance it worked fine.